# How to show that $\sum_{i=2}^{n} 1/(i \log i)$ is $\Theta (\log \log n)$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Could someone explain me how to solve this problem, please?

Let $f(n) = \sum_{i=2}^{n} \left(\frac{1}{i\log{}i}\right)$ where log denotes the natural logarithm.

Show that $f(n)=\Theta (\log\log{}n)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a comparison series/integral for this (have you ever encountered one of these? This basically amounts to arguing that $\sum_{k=2}^n f(k) \simeq \int_{2}^n f(x)dx$, for a monotone (say, non-increasing) function $f$, by using the fact that $$f(k+1) = \int_k^{k+1} f(k+1) dx \leq \int_k^{k+1} f(x) dx \leq \int_k^{k+1} f(k) dx = f(k)$$ by monotonicity of $f$, and summing the inequalities for $k=2$ to $n$.)
A useful fact to conclude is that $\int^t \frac{dx}{x \ln x} = \ln\ln t$.

Comment: thank you for your answer !